# Request: Update or Insert rows from the same table

Tags: sql, insert, merge, db2

I work with the db2 SQL database and got the following task: There is this scheme XXWWF590 with the table XXWWC5 in it. The table itself contains different columns e.g. the delivery number, delivery adresses such as Name, Street, Postal Code and so on. There is also a column called production site, which has different numbers for different sites in it(like 100 for company 1, 200 for company 2 etc.)
This is where it gets tricky: I was demanded to duplicate all the entries from the column "production site" with the number 500, to the rows with production site 600, if they already exist, they shall be overwritten, if not, inserted - and I don't know how the hell I am supposed to do that.

Here's an excerpt of the table so you can better imagine what I mean:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|           | (ColA) - Site   | (ColB)Del.Adress |
--------------------------------------------------
| Row1      | (CellA1) 500    | (CellB1) Berlin  |
--------------------------------------------------
| Row2      | (CellA2) 500    | (CellB2) Munich  |
--------------------------------------------------
| Row3      | (CellA3) 600    | (CellB3) Berlin  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

There are a lot more columns and rows, and they are also not called "Site" or delivery adress but have cryptic name such as C5BSTX, but that doesn't matter in this case. Just keep that in mind when you take a look at my statements.

Because of the request to overwrite as well as to insert. I came up with the idea of merging the table, so i tried, but never finished the statement, simply because I thought I can't merge data from one table into the same table. Nevertheless; Here's what I wrote thus far:

```
MERGE INTO WWC5REP AS a
USING (SELECT C5ATCD, C5BSTX, C5BTTX, C5BVTX, C5OXT1, C5BXTX, C5TETY
WHERE C5ENCD = '500') AS a_tmp
FROM WWC5REP
ON a.C5ATCD = a_tmp.C5ATCD
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET
( a.C5BSTX = a_tmp.C5BSTX
, a.C5BTTX = a_tmp.C5BTTX
, a.C5BUTX = a_tmp.C5BUTX
, a.C5BVTX = a_tmp.C5BVTX
, a.C5OXT1 = a_tmp.C5OXT1
, a.C5HTTX = a_tmp.C5HTTX
, a.C5BXTX = a_tmp.C5BXTX
, a.C5TETY = a_tmp.C5TETY
, a.C5AAST = '0'
, a.C5ABDT = 11500407
, a.C5AATM = 101500
, a.C5DBCD = '99222'
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
( a.C5BSTX
, a.C5BTTX
, a.C5BUTX
, a.C5BVTX
, a.C5OXT1
, a.C5HTTX
, a.C5BXTX
, a.C5TETY
, a.C5AAST
, a.C5ABDT
, a.C5AATM
, a.C5DBCD
)
VALUES
( a_tmp.C5BSTX
, a_tmp.C5BTTX
, a_tmp.C5BUTX
, a_tmp.C5BVTX
, a_tmp.C5OXT1
, a_tmp.C5HTTX
, a_tmp.C5BXTX
, a_tmp.C5TETY
, '0'              
, 1150402                                                           
, 101500
, '99222'
)
```

The C5ATCD column is, in my opinion the primary key, because both sites (500 and 600) have the same value in that column.

Next thing i thought of, was an update, but that did work just as good as the merge.

```
UPDATE WWC5REP AS a
SET a.C5BSTX = b.C5BSTX, a.C5BTTX = b.C5BTTX, a.C5BUTX = b.C5BUTX,
    a.C5BVTX = b.C5BVTX, a.C5OXT1 = b.C5OXT1, a.C5HTTX = b.C5HTTX,
    a.C5BXTX = b.C5BXTX, a.C5TETY = b.C5TETY, a.C5AAST = '0', a.C5ABDT = 1150401, 
    a.C5AATM = 101500, a.C5DBCD = '99222' 
FROM WWC5REP AS b
WHERE a.C5ENCD IN ('600') 
AND b.C5ENCD IN ('600')
ON a.C5ATCD = b.C5ATCD
```

Which finally led me to try and Insert the data but honestly, my head is spinnin around and I definitely need help with that.

Comment: You got your merge statement almost right. Yes, you can use fir the same table. There are a couple of problems. First of all in your using clause you have forgotten to specify a FROM statement. It needs to be there. Secondly, instead of selecting your site code you need to type '600' as C5BSTX. That way you will select the entries fir the site 500, but will make them as 600 straight away in you USING clause.

Comment: First of all thanks, for the support. I tried the statement you suggested, but I keep getting the " [SQL0104] Token '=' not valid. "-Error. It's obvious, that there must be some sort of typo but I can't figure out where.

Comment: I fixed the issue with the Token by simply deleting the "( )" from the Update clause, but now I get an [SQL0788] Error, stating, that there are duplicative values in the on clause (C5ATCD - the delivery number) Unfortenately, this column is the only one I can use as a primary key. I will try and fix this, too, but I'd appreciate anything you might come up with.

Comment: This is because you are not inserting C5ATCD. I have updated the answer

Comment: Yes that finally worked, my table has now been fully updated. Thank you very much cha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment your merge statement is almost right. Below is the one that will do the job

```
MERGE INTO WWC5REP AS a
USING (SELECT '600' as C5ATCD, C5BSTX, C5BTTX, C5BVTX, C5OXT1, C5BXTX, C5TETY
FROM WWC5REP
WHERE C5ENCD = '500') AS a_tmp
ON a.C5ATCD = a_tmp.C5ATCD
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET
  a.C5BSTX = a_tmp.C5BSTX
, a.C5BTTX = a_tmp.C5BTTX
, a.C5BUTX = a_tmp.C5BUTX
, a.C5BVTX = a_tmp.C5BVTX
, a.C5OXT1 = a_tmp.C5OXT1
, a.C5HTTX = a_tmp.C5HTTX
, a.C5BXTX = a_tmp.C5BXTX
, a.C5TETY = a_tmp.C5TETY
, a.C5AAST = '0'
, a.C5ABDT = 11500407
, a.C5AATM = 101500
, a.C5DBCD = '99222'
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
( a.C5ATCD
, a.C5BSTX
, a.C5BTTX
, a.C5BUTX
, a.C5BVTX
, a.C5OXT1
, a.C5HTTX
, a.C5BXTX
, a.C5TETY
, a.C5AAST
, a.C5ABDT
, a.C5AATM
, a.C5DBCD
)
VALUES
( a_tmp.C5ATCD
, a_tmp.C5BSTX
, a_tmp.C5BTTX
, a_tmp.C5BUTX
, a_tmp.C5BVTX
, a_tmp.C5OXT1
, a_tmp.C5HTTX
, a_tmp.C5BXTX
, a_tmp.C5TETY
, '0'              
, 1150402                                                           
, 101500
, '99222'
)
```